# Is it bad write different files from different threads?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsdata

Writing a data on main thread and a file on background tread:

[image]

`d.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true) //d is NSDictionary`

and

`[archiveData writeToFile:randomPath atomically:YES]; //archiveData  is NSData`

But they are not refering the same location. Is it possible though app will crash?

Comment: The correct term for what will happen here is "undefined behaviour". It might crash, it might not crash, it might write your data correctly, you might think it has worked but find the actual data is corrupt or incorrect. It's always better to properly manage how and when (and from where) files are written. "Undefined behaviour" is never a good thing.

Comment: So you suggest write all the data - even though they are distinct - always from the same serial tread?

Comment: NSDictionary `writeToFile:atomically:` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You say "but they are not referring to the same location". How do you know? Can you guarantee it? There's nothing in your code that forbids it. How do you know that `filePath` and `randomPath` won't be the same path? Don't gamble. Coordinate your file writes. (The easiest way is to perform them all on the main thread, but it isn't the only way, and it might not be sufficient; for example you could be using an NSFileCoordinator here.)

Comment: Logic guarantees that `randomPath` is always has extension `.7z` and `filePath` is `.plist`.

Comment: Maybe. And maybe not.